# Подключить java библиотеку к qt проекту под Android (notification-hubs-04.jar)

Tags: android, qt, azure

Нужно подключить [ms azure sdk](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/downloads/) или одну библиотеку notification-hubs-0.4.jar (или *0.3.jar) из этого sdk. Есть [пример от ms azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/). В нём библиотека подключается для сборки с помощью Grandle. С Grandle собрать получилось. Но хочется обойтись без него.

Подскажите, как подключить java библиотеку к qt проекту под Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Мануал от qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android3rdpartylibs.html)

Так как ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR в проекте уже был настроен, осталось поместить notification-hubs-0.4.jar в директорию resources\android\libs

Реальной причиной ошибки при компиляции в моём проекте было отсутствие библиотеки notifications-1.0.1.jar. Её помещаем рядом с notification-hubs-0.4.jar.

Если реализовывать [пример от азуре](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/) и прописать в манифесте

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"...
```

то проекту понадобится библиотека google-play-services_lib. Её тоже нужно скопировать в проект. В моём случае её нужно было обновить, так как в проекте лежала старая версия, в которой класс GcmReceiver не был реализован.